# У книгах має бути "покажчик" чи "показник"?

Tags: суфікси, іменники

Нещодавно, збираючи книгу з latex-сирців із використанням пакета `babel` із параметром `ukrainian`

```
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
```

я отримав отакий вихід в pdf (тобто, слово *покажчик* зашито в пакеті і використалось автоматично):

[image]

Та один знавець справи сказав мені, що *покажчик* - це неправильно, бо суфікс *-чик* в українській мові зменшувальний, як-от у *хлопець/хлопчик*, і має бути *показник*.

Але ж є багато слів, що завершуються на *-чик* і не носять зменшувального забарвлення, де правда?

Comment: покажчик - прибор який вимірює певні показники

Comment: http://sum.in.ua/s/pokazhchyk [...] 2. Контрольно-вимірювальний прилад. [...] 4. заст. Те саме, що показник 1, 2.

давач - то сенсор, напевно, частина покажчика

Comment: @chizh цікаво, що на Вікі з'явився новий варіант *датник* і це говорить за *показник*

Answer (score 7):

Мабуть, я погарячкував з [попередньою відповіддю](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/revisions/804/2).

З одного боку, слово «покажчик» (враховуючи майже безперервне вживання з 1895 року) **ніяк не можна назвати нерідним** для української мови.

З іншого боку, **мова змінюється**, із часом виявляються нові закономірності і вона теоретично може з часом позбуватися слів, що робили її менш послідовною. Тож можливість, що суфікс «-чик» колись стане неприйнятним для цієї ролі, я в цілому припускаю. Але от чи став він вже таким (дійсно, а не в уяві пуристів) — питання дуже дискусійне.

Маємо такі варіанти:

- **Вказівни́к/указівни́к** — нормативний у [СУМ-20 (III, 2012)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=206368&page=490) і [Кочерги та Мейнаровича (2010)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=5); і, можливо, *вказі́вник* (інший наголос) — згадується в [Ніковського](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=ukr&dicts=8).
- **Пока́жчик** — принаймні згадується в [СУМ-20 (III, 2012)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=206368&page=490), не основний у [Кочерги та Мейнаровича (2010)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=5), нормативний у [СУМ-11 (I, 1970)](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokazhchyk), нормативний чи згадується в деяких інших.
- **Пока́зник** — нормативний у [Кочерги та Мейнаровича (2010)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=5), забороняється у [СУМ-11 (I, 1970)](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokaznyk), нормативний чи згадується в деяких інших.
- <sub>У специфічних сферах:</sub>

  - <sub>*Газетир* — алфавітний перелік географічний.</sub>

### Радянські часи

Згідно з СУМ-11 (том I, 1970), слово **«показник» не можна застосовувати у цьому значенні**, тому що воно його не має:

> **[Пока́зник](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokaznyk)**: **1.** Свідчення, доказ, ознака чого-небудь. **2.** *перев. мн.* Наочні дані про результати якоїсь роботи / Дані, які свідчать про кількість чого-небудь. **3.** *рідко.* Те саме, що *покажчик 1*. ▲ Показник степеня, *мат.*
>   *<sub>[Примітка від мене: «покажчик 1» — це лише «напис або який-небудь знак (стрілка, тичка і т. ін.)», а не будь-які значення слова «покажчик».]</sub>*

А от слово **«покажчик» має потрібне значення**:

> **[Пока́жчик](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokazhchyk)**: <…> **3.** Довідкова книжка або довідковий список, доданий до книжки. <…>

Цю думку поділяють деякі автори радянських і пізніших часів:

- Борис Рогоза в [«Уроках державної мови»](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/178.htm) (в газеті «Хрещатик», рік невідомий).
- Євгенія Чак у книзі [«Складні випадки українського слововживання»](http://lib.misto.kiev.ua/UKR/VPRAVA/MOVA/SKLADNE_SLOVOVJIVANNA/pokaznik_pokajchik.dhtml) (1969) та посібнику [«Чи правильно ми говоримо?»](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/p#pokaznyk-pokazhchyk) (1997).

### Сучасні часи

- «Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» (О. Кочерга та Є. Мейнарович, 2010) як переклад англійського «index» (саме в потрібному значенні — у книжці) пропонує використовувати [«**вказівни́к**, **пока́зник**» (а окремі словосполучення перекладає лише зі словом «**пока́зник**», без «вказівника»)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=index&dicts=4&main_only=on).

  Слово «покажчик» [узагалі не згадується](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=4) в англійсько-українському словнику, а в українсько-англійському [є лише посиланням на «пока́зник»](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=5&main_only=on).

  Слід зазначити, що цей словник розрізняє за наголосом варіанти «показни́к» (наприклад, величина) і «пока́зник» (наприклад, книжковий) (хоча в англійсько-українському томі в наголосах часто безлад) — чого не робить, наприклад, СУМ-11.
- СУМ-20 (том III, 2012), не допомагаючи з «покажчиком»/«показником» (оскільки ще не має літери «п»), пропонує слово «**вказівни́к**»:

  > **[Вказівни́к (указівни́к)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=206368&page=490)**: **2.** Довідник у формі книги або списку додатків до неї; покажчик, індекс, каталог і т. ін.

  Update: Тільки зараз помітив, що у вищенаведеній цитаті СУМ-20 побічно згадує і «покажчик». Тож, імовірніше за все, СУМ-20 поділяє погляди СУМ-11 на нормативність слова «покажчик» (але от його погляди на нормативність слова «показник» у цьому значенні — невідомі).

### Старіші часи

Слово «покажчик» (іноді у написанні «пока**зч**ик», що я особисто вважаю лище орфографічним варіантом) вживається:

- Журнал «Життє і слово» за 1895 рік декілька разів містить «покажчик», саме в потрібному значенні (а слова «показник» у тих томах немає):

  - [Том III](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Zhytie_i_slovo/1895_Tom_3/), І. Франко «ХІХ. Уклінна просьба» ([стор. 479, рядки 8–9 з кінця](//books.google.com/books?id=jnAyAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)).
  - [Том IV](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Zhytie_i_slovo/1895_Tom_4/), А. Кримський «Про рукописи Руданського» (стор. 263, абзац 2, рядок 7: [1](//books.google.com/books?id=vXAyAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=mx1JAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)).
  - [Том IV](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Zhytie_i_slovo/1895_Tom_4/), І. Заневич «Літературні стремліня галицьких Русинів» ([стор. 433, абзац 2, рядок 11](//books.google.com/books?id=SX1EAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)).
- Журнали самого кінця XIX ст. – самого початку XX взагалі часто використовують слово «показчик» (але в гугл-книгах треба шукати «показник», бо механізми розпізнавання тексту використовують сучасні словники і воно розпізнається як «показник» — але при перегляді видно «показчик»): 
  [1](//books.google.com/books?id=d8VBAAAAYAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [2](//books.google.com/books?id=Z7EWAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [3](//books.google.com/books?id=PndUAAAAYAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [4](//books.google.com/books?id=WlgxAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [5](//books.google.com/books?id=hA7UAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [6](//books.google.com/books?id=e1o9AQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [7](//books.google.com/books?id=n0soAQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [8](//books.google.com/books?id=W0bnAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [9](//books.google.com/books?id=e23UAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [10](//books.google.com/books?id=iNpDAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [11](//books.google.com/books?id=HPXgAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [12](//books.google.com/books?id=h3hQAAAAYAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), 
  [13](//books.google.com/books?id=VFU8AQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA).
- [«Словарь росийсько-український» (М. Уманець, А. Спілка; том III–IV; 1896–1898)](http://r2u.org.ua/html/other_dicts.html) містить «покажчик», точні значення невідомі:

  - [<sub>рос.</sub> показатель](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&scope=rusb&dicts=9): *пока́з(ж)чик*, *пока́зник*, *ука́зник*, *ука́зчик* (*-ця*);
  - [<sub>рос.</sub> указатель](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&scope=rusb&dicts=9): *ука́зник*, *ука́ж(з)чик*, *пока́ж(з)чик* (але не *показник*).
- «Словарь української мови» (Б. Грінченко; 1909) ([1](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/42427-pokazchyk.html#show_point), [2](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=38404&page=848), [3](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=ukrq&dicts=12)) містить «пока́**зч**ик» (інших варіантів, наприклад «показника», нема), здається, в потрібному значенні («показчик до приказок»).
- [«Словник українсько-російський» (А. Ніковський; 1927)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&scope=rus&dicts=8) містить: «вказі́вка», «вказі́вник», «пока́жчик», «пока́зник», «ука́жчик» — точні значення невідомі.
- [«Російсько-український фразеологічний словник» (В. Підмогильний, Є. Плужник; 1927–1928)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&scope=rusb&dicts=3) містить «покажчик» (інших немає) — саме в потрібному значенні.
- «Російсько-український словник» (О. Ізюмов; 1930) містить «[пока́жчик](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=ukrq&dicts=2&highlight=on)» — точні значення невідомі:

  - <sub>рос.</sub> выразитель (показатель): *пока́жчик*;
  - <sub>рос.</sub> индекс: *і́ндекс*, *пока́жчик*;
  - <sub>рос.</sub> указатель: *пока́жчик*;
  - <sub>рос.</sub> явитель (-ница): *пред’я́вник* (*-ця*), *пока́жчик* (*-ця*).

  <sub>Також він містить і «[пока́зник](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=ukrq&dicts=2&highlight=on)» — точні значення невідомі:</sub>

  - <sub><sub>рос.</sub> показатель (-ница): *пока́зник* (*-ця*);</sub>
  - <sub><sub>рос.</sub> показчик: *пока́зник*.</sub>
- «Російсько-український академічний словник» (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов; 1933) мість лише «[пока́жчик](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=ukrq&dicts=1&highlight=on)» — в т. ч. саме в потрібному значенні і «[пока́зчик](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=ukrq&dicts=1&highlight=on)» — точні значення незрозумілі (але «показника» немає).

Answer (score 6):

Для з’ясування таких питань чудово підходить [Інверсійний словник української мови](http://ereadr.org/book/nauka_i_ucheba/10210-inversijnij-slovnik-ukrayinskoyi-movi/2), в якому слова розташовано в алфавітному порядку не за першими, а за останніми літерами слова. Слова, що закінчуються на *-чик* там знаходяться [на ст. 460](http://ereadr.org/book/nauka_i_ucheba/10210-inversijnij-slovnik-ukrayinskoyi-movi/461)–462. Хоча більшість із цих слів дійсно є зменшувальними формами, та є й инші випадки.

Зокрема, є слова, в яких *-чик* колись скоріш за все був зменшувальним, та тепер таким вже не є, як от *рябчик*.

В багатьох словах *-чик* є суфіксом професії, роду занять: *наладчик*, *цукрозаводчик*, *наводчик*, *[на]льотчик*, тощо.

Є слова, що закінчуються на *-чик*, та суфіксом є тільки *-ик*, а *ч* – це частина кореня: *пілсудчик*, *глечик*, тощо.

Та все одно, більше, ніж 90% цих слів є зменшувальними формами. Незважаючи на це, слово *покажчик* у значенні «довідковий список, доданий до книжки» [зареєстровано](http://sum.in.ua/s/Pokazhchyk) в СУМ-11, тому не турбуйтеся, ви все правильно написали.

Comment: От, той дядько якраз і сказав, що використання *-чик* в льотчик показує, що це не українське слово.

Comment: @Yola - То можу замінити _льотчик_ на _небіжчик_. ))

Answer (score 1):

Той-таки дядько написав мені відповідь на те, що тут написано, ось вона:

> Коротко. В словниках є і показник, і покажчик [у сенсі
>   показатель]. Другий – помилка. Але користувачі на тому сайті можуть
>   спробувати вивести появу такої конструкції покаж+чик. Як з’являється
>   показник: показувати, показ, показник. Хай виведуть такий ряд для
>   покажчика
>
> Стосовно "В багатьох словах *-чик* є суфіксом професії, роду
>   занять: наладчик, цукрозаводчик, наводчик, [на]льотчик, тощо", то можу
>   сказати, що діти користуються суто совковими джерелами, починаючи з
>   правопису чи того ж СУМу.
>
> Наладчик українською наладник. А наладчик
>   він якраз у СУМі. **НАЛА́ДЧИК**, а, чол. *Робітник, що налагоджує машини,
>   станки, механізми і т. ін. На автоматизованому виробництві основною
>   фігурою є наладчик* (**Комуніст України**, 9, 1963, 31); *Молодь освоїть тут
>   [в училищах] нові професії — наладчиків автоматів і автоматичних ліній*
>   (**Радянська Україна**, 2.VIII 1959, 4).
>
> **Налё́тчик, -чица** – наско́чник, -ниця, (грабитель, -ница) грабі́жник,
>   -ниця.
>
> **Наво́дчик, -чица** –  1) (мастер) навідни́к (-ка́), -ни́ця, (золотом)
>   позлі́тник (-ка), -ниця, золотни́к (-ка́), -ни́ця, золота́р (-ря́),
>   -та́рка;  2) (зачинщик) призві́дник, -ниця до чо́го, на що;  3) (в преступн. мире) навідни́к, -ни́ця;  4) -чик (в артиллерии) –
>   наці́лювач чого́.
>
> небіжчик теж не українське слово.
>
> І останнє. Я не просто дядько, я дуже моцний дядько

А ось і словник в якому зустрічаються частина з наданих перекладів: [Російсько-український словник ділової мови](http://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%20(1930).pdf) М.Дорошенко, М.Станиславський, В.Страшкевич
**1930**

Comment: 1 JFYI [тут](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine4-2.pdf) одна з авторок СУМ-11 подає відомості про -чик, -щик ще у досовкові часи і тогочасну динаміку

2 запрошай моцного дядька сюди і нехай він сам сюди пруфлінки постить

Comment: Я [оновив відповідь](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/804/4). Я припускаю, що «дядько» може бути правий щодо **сучасних мовних тенденцій**, але не щодо **історії розвитку мови** (враховуючи, що «покажчик» саме в цьому значенні використовується, як мінімум, з 1895 року в журналі за редакцією Івана Франка). Але я вже не сперечаюся проти слова «пока́зник» у цьому значенні (воно, як виявилося, теж має свою давню історію).

Comment: @chizh я до нього поїду можливо через місяць, може раніше, тоді підготуюсь і викладу йому докази, і відпишу сюди.